# Will there be an official Stack Exchange application for Android?

Tags: support, app-request, android

I have really liked the experience on the various associated Stack Exchange sites and had the mobile application for Android until recently I switched mobiles and had to uninstall it.  I also personally really miss the ease and efficiency of the application and personally find the mobile site on the mobile (although very usable and brilliantly adapted especially when compared to other sites) just not as convenient as the application. Seeing as there is an application for iOS (as far as my understanding goes) and that having an application is extremely optimized and allows users to engage and interact more often and much more fluidly I wanted to know will there be another Stack Exchange application for Android?

I am really sorry if this is a repeated question or is not suited for this website,(I joined this specific website for specifically this question) but I could not find any other such questions/plans and simply could not resist the temptation to ask it.

Answer (score 1):

No. There was one (I still have it on my phone), but support has been discontinued. (That also holds for the iOS app, but that one is somehow still listed in the App Store). To quote [one of the developers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/295232):

> We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app (even for breaking bugs). We encourage all mobile users to use the responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the user experience for mobile users.

Comment: I think android users cant even download the StackExchange app now